# Use selenium to control which bar plot to click on, rect nodes in highcharts

Tags: python, selenium

I am struggling with programming selenium to click on a bar plot (highcharts) that would open a new tab. It seems my xpath is not correct. I used this site: [freeformatter-XML](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) and checked my xpath, and I am able to retrieve the corresponding rect node, however it does not open a new tab when I run this code. When I tried adding `return hoverChart` it gives me an empty list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("www.website.com")
chart_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-series-group']")
hoverChart_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='g' and @data-z-index='0.1']//rect[2]") #try to click on the second rect node
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(chart_element).click(hoverChart_element).perform()
```

---

making a generic xpath to the highcharts works (a new tab opens), but I can't iteratively click each of the following bars on the barplot. This way only opens the fist and I can't control which bar plot gets opened.

```
chart_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-series-group']//*[name()='rect']")
ActionChains(driver).click(chart_element).perform()
```

[image: image of source]

Comment: Do you want to click on each `rect` node one by one and do something on each opened new tab? What do you mean by saying *"I can't control which bar plot gets opened"*?

Comment: yes, exactly what you said. Each bar in the bar plot opens a link (which is a rect node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to click each `rect` node and handle elements on new tabs:

```
main_tab = driver.current_window_handle

for rect in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-series-group']//*[name()='rect']"):
    ActionChains(driver).click(rect).perform()
    print('Checking rectangle with (X={}, Y={}) coordinates'.format(rect.get_attribute('x'), rect.get_attribute('y')))
    driver.switch_to.window([tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab != main_tab][0])
    # Do something on new tab
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(main_tab)
```

Comment: great, thanks. i got it to work after changing `rect.click()` to `ActionChains(driver).click(rect).perform()` and the '{' and '}' in the print line to '(' and ')'